# Проблема с присвоением нужных цветов через StyleSheet

Tags: python, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, qss, qthread

Не могу изменить текст с красного на зеленый в элементе `QTextEdit`.

Выбивает вот такую вот ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtBoundSignal' object has no attribute 'setStyleSheet'

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class ThreadClass2(QtCore.QThread,QMessageBox):
    MySignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, getIP, parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.getIP = getIP

    def run(self):


        try:
            ipaddress.ip_network(self.getIP)

            url = 'http://www.ip-score.com/ajax_handler/get_bls'

            blacklist = [
                'access.redhawk.org', 'b.barracudacentral.org', 'bl.shlink.org', 'bl.spamcannibal.org',
                'bl.spamcop.net', 'bl.tiopan.com', 'blackholes.wirehub.net', 'blacklist.sci.kun.nl',
                'block.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'blocked.hilli.dk', 'bogons.cymru.com', 'cart00ney.surriel.com',
                'cbl.abuseat.org', 'cblless.anti-spam.org.cn', 'dev.null.dk', 'dialup.blacklist.jippg.org',
                'dialups.mail-abuse.org', 'dialups.visi.com', 'dnsbl.abuse.ch', 'dnsbl.anticaptcha.net',
                'dnsbl.antispam.or.id', 'dnsbl.dronebl.org', 'dnsbl.justspam.org', 'dnsbl.kempt.net',
                'dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'dnsbl.tornevall.org', 'dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net', 'duinv.aupads.org',
                'dnsbl-2.uceprotect.net', 'dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net', 'dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'dul.ru',
                'escalations.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'hil.habeas.com', 'black.junkemailfilter.com',
                'http.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'intruders.docs.uu.se', 'ips.backscatterer.org',
                'korea.services.net', 'l2.apews.org', 'mail-abuse.blacklist.jippg.org',
                'misc.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'msgid.bl.gweep.ca', 'new.dnsbl.sorbs.net',
                'no-more-funn.moensted.dk', 'old.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'opm.tornevall.org', 'pbl.spamhaus.org',
                'proxy.bl.gweep.ca', 'psbl.surriel.com', 'pss.spambusters.org.ar', 'rbl.schulte.org',
                'rbl.snark.net', 'recent.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'relays.bl.gweep.ca', 'relays.bl.kundenserver.de',
                'relays.mail-abuse.org', 'relays.nether.net', 'rsbl.aupads.org', 'sbl.spamhaus.org',
                'smtp.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'socks.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'spam.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'spam.olsentech.net',
                'spamguard.leadmon.net', 'spamsources.fabel.dk', 'tor.dnsbl.sectoor.de', 'ubl.unsubscore.com',
                'web.dnsbl.sorbs.net', 'xbl.spamhaus.org', 'zen.spamhaus.org', 'zombie.dnsbl.sorbs.net',
                'dnsbl.inps.de', 'dyn.shlink.org', 'rbl.megarbl.net', 'bl.mailspike.net']

            for server in blacklist:
                try:
                    data = {'ip': self.getIP, 'server': server}

                    response = requests.post(url, data=data, timeout=3)

                    if response.status_code != 200:
                        raise ValueError('Expected 200 OK')

                    data = response.json()

                    rating = data[data.keys()[0]]

                    if rating != "":
                        self.MySignal.emit(server + "LISTED " + rating)

                except:
                      self.MySignal.emit("NOT LISTED: " + server)
                      self.MySignal.setStyleSheet("background-color:black;color:green;") ## Проблемная строчка
        except ValueError:

             self.MySignal.emit('Invalid IP!')
```

Окно:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    # ?   lineEdit_2: QLineEdit
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1321, 934)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2421, 921))
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(801, 0))
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover {\n"
                                     "  background-color:silver\n"
                                     "}")
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color:black")
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.wh1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 39, 181, 41))
        self.wh1.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh1.setText("")
        self.wh1.setObjectName("wh1")
        self.wh2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 70, 181, 31))
        self.wh2.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh2.setText("")
        self.wh2.setObjectName("wh2")
        self.wh3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 80, 181, 61))
        self.wh3.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh3.setText("")
        self.wh3.setObjectName("wh3")
        self.wh4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 110, 181, 51))
        self.wh4.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh4.setText("")
        self.wh4.setObjectName("wh4")
        self.wh5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 130, 181, 61))
        self.wh5.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh5.setText("")
        self.wh5.setObjectName("wh5")
        self.wh6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 160, 181, 51))
        self.wh6.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh6.setText("")
        self.wh6.setObjectName("wh6")
        self.wh7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 180, 421, 61))
        self.wh7.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh7.setText("")
        self.wh7.setObjectName("wh7")
        self.wh8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.wh8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 250, 261, 81))
        self.wh8.setStyleSheet("color:red;")
        self.wh8.setText("")
        self.wh8.setObjectName("wh8")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.textEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.textEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_5.setStyleSheet("background-color:black;color:red;")
        self.textEdit_5.setObjectName("textEdit_5")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 22, 111, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 15, 431, 31))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
        self.label_3.setToolTipDuration(-7)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color:black;")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_4.setStyleSheet("background-color:black;color:red;")
        self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1321, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        self.textEdit_2.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit_4.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit_5.setReadOnly(True)
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick Чтобы вкладка LISTED выводилась зеленым цветом.Пример прикрепил выше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите строку `self.MySignal.setStyleSheet("background-color: black; color: green;")`

Замените строку

```
self.MySignal.emit(server + "LISTED " + rating)
```

на

```
self.MySignal.emit(server + \
        '<b style="background-color: black; color: green;">LISTED</b>' + \
        rating)
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!